# Probability and when to take into account the # of ways something can be done?

Tags: probability

In this probability question:

Sixty percent of the 350 seniors at a certain school stated that they make calls with their smartphones. Of those who make calls, forty percent also send text messages. If two students are selected at random, what is the probability of selecting one student who both makes calls and sends text messages and one student who only makes calls?

The answer given is 8.7% because it is (84/350)(126/349).

I'm wondering why we don't take into account the number of ways that student can be chosen, so that it is (84/350)(126/349) + (126/350)(84/349) = 17.4%.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the answer is wrong. This is easier to see if you imagine the students to consist of two groups of equal size. The probability to select one from each group when you randomly select two is roughly $1/2$, not, as the answer would have it, roughly $1/4$. The answer would be correct if the question were about the probability to select the students in the order given.